# while scrolling inner scrollbar page scrolls

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have 3 divs with scrollbar. if we move one scrollbar and it reaches end of scrolling area page also scrolls.

I want to fix this issue.

Fiddle for it. http://jsfiddle.net/78h8e88x/2/

```
html, body {
height: 100%;
 position:relative;
}

  body
 {

line-height:100px;
text-align:center;
}

  .left
 {
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:5%;
  margin-top:3%;
  display:block;
  height:80%;
   width:20%;

  overflow:auto;
 }

  .center
 {
 position:absolute;
 margin-left:25%;
 margin-top:3%;
 display:block;
 height:80%;
 width:50%;

 overflow:auto;
  }

 .right
 {
  position:absolute;
   margin-left:75%;
   margin-top:3%;
   display:block;
  height:80%;
   width:20%;

  overflow:auto;
 }
```

if we move one scrollbar and it reaches end of scrolling area page also scrolls.

Comment: You could disable the overflow of your [body](http://jsfiddle.net/78h8e88x/3/).

Comment: @RienNeVaPlu͢s i cant do that because there is some content below

Answer (score 2):

The body element gets a margin of 8px by default (in Chrome at least). In the case of your fiddle this makes the content slightly bigger then the window and thus a scrollbar appears. Setting the margin to 0 on the body will remove this scrollbar. See jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vbvmLbmq/

That of course only fixes the scrolling behaviour in your fiddle which was a matter of window size. You can prevent scrolling on the html,body elements entirely by adding the `overflow: hidden;` css rule to them but keep in mind that would also hide any elements that flow past the height of those elements.

Continuing the scrolling of the page after a child elements scrolling has reached its end is browser application behaviour, which you cannot influence with javascript on your page.